# display:none não está sendo aplicado

Tags: jquery, css3

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
  function exibeSelectUl () {

      $(".selectOptions ul > li").each(function() {

          alert($.trim($(this).text()) +'==='+ $.trim($(".selectOptions .selecionada").html()));

          if($.trim($(this).text()) === $.trim($(".selectOptions .selecionada").html())) 
               $(this).css("display","none");
          else 
               $(this).css("display","block");
      });

  }
```

O objetivo aqui é passar por cada **li** e verificar se seu **html()** é igual ao **text()** de uma **div** que existe no código. Caso o seja, esta **li** terá seu **display** setado para **none**.

Como podem notar, existe um **alert** que mostra isso e, em uma das opções, sempre a condição será verdadeira. porém o **display:none** não está sendo aplicado.

Onde está o erro?

Isso pode ser verificado em

http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/aa.php

Comment: Você já tentou substituir o === por == somente?

Comment: sim, mesma coisa. Será que estou aplicando** $(this).css('display','none');** ao elemento correto?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você quer fazer um select usando uma lista <ul>. Quando eu clico na lista, aparecem as opções "um", "dois", "três" e "quatro". Quando eu clico na opção "três", por exemplo, as outras somem, indicando que eu selecionei a opção "três". Qual seria o erro então? Reproduzi no JSFiddle e está sumindo normalmente as opções não selecionadas.

Comment: Quando você clica na seta para baixo (**abre a select**) pela primeira vez depois que abre a página, note que existe uma opção repetida. Percebeu? Então, o objetivo dessa função é exatamente este: comparar o texto da **div** com o texto html da **li**, caso sejam iguais, **display:none** na dita **li**. E, este **display:none** não está sendo aplicado na dita **li**. Ou seja, ela está sendo exibida na **ul** Porém observe que, quando abre a pagina pela primeira vez e ainda não clicou na select, se você ver no **inspector**, notará uma li com **display none**

Answer (score 0):

Adicione ao seu CSS uma classe contendo o `display:none`:

```
.hidden {
  display:none !important;
}
```

No código que adiciona as options do select na lista, cheque se a option está selecionada, se estiver, adicione o elemento à lista como já estava sendo feito, porém com a classe **'hidden'** (adicionei também a classe **'opcaoLista'** só para facilitar selecionar os `li` depois):

```
if($(this).is(':selected')){
    $(".selectOptions ul").append("<li class='opcaoLista hidden' value='"+this.value+"' >"+this.text+"</li>");
} 
else {
    $(".selectOptions ul").append("<li class='opcaoLista' value='"+this.value+"'>"+this.text+"</li>");
}
```

No método **exibeSelectUl**, adicione ou remova a classe 'hidden', em vez do .css("display", "none):

```
 $(".opcaoLista").each(function() {
      //alert($.trim($(this).text()) +'==='+ $.trim($(".selectOptions .selecionada").html()));
      if($.trim($(this).text()) === $.trim($(".selectOptions .selecionada").html())){
         $(this).addClass("hidden");
      } else {
         $(this).removeClass("hidden");
         $(this).show();
      }
  });
```

Link para o exemplo no [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KXQzBB)

Comment: Entendi o que você fez mas não entendi o porque o código reagiu assim. Porque que quando você cria uma classe para **display:none** e chama ela a partir do **jQuery** funciona e quando eu faço $(this).css("display","none");, não funciona?

Comment: Outra dúvida: porque é que foi necessário remover a classe **hidden**, , para depois sim, chamar a classe **shown**? Porque é que não dá certo apenas fazendo **display:block** ?

Comment: E, porque foi necessário adicionar **!important** ao display?

Comment: Foi necessário remover a classe **hidden** porque ela está marcada com o **!important**, impedindo que o `.show()` funcione.

Answer (score 0):

@renato-diniz, baseado na tua orientação, estudei bastante o teu código e então concertei o meu.

Gostaria que avaliasse e me dissesse o que achou.

Pode ser visualizado online em http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/

Ficou assim:

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.selectOptions {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:35px;    
}
.selectOptions select {
    display:none;
}
.selectOptions .selecionada {
    display:block;

}
.selectOptions .selecionada:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    background-image: url(../_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg);
}
.selectOptions .selecionada.setaBaixo:after {
    background-image: url(../_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg);
}
.selectOptions .selecionada.setaCima:after {
    background-image: url(../_imgs/setaCima.jpg);
}

.selectOptions ul {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
}
.selectOptions ul li{
    cursor:pointer;
}

.selectOptions ul li,
.selectOptions .selecionada {
    position:relative;
    width:94%;
    height:34px;
    line-height:34px;   
    padding:0 3% 0 3%; 
    border-bottom: rgb(200,200,200) 1px solid;
    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
}

.selectOptions  ul li:hover,
.selectOptions  .selecionada {
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  /*
    $('form').submit((function(e) {

       }
    ));
  */

  $(".selectOptions .selecionada").html($(".selectOptions select > option:first-child").html());
  /*popula as li's*/
  $(".selectOptions select > option").each(function() {
      if($(this).is(':first-child')) $(".selectOptions ul").append("<li value='"+this.value+"' style='display:none;'>"+this.text+"</li>");    
      else $(".selectOptions ul").append("<li style='display:block;' value='"+this.value+"'>"+this.text+"</li>");
  });

  function exibeSelectUl () {

      $(".selectOptions ul > li").each(function() {

          if($.trim($(this).text()) === $.trim($(".selectOptions .selecionada").html())) 
               $(this).css("display","none", "important");
          else   
               $(this).css("display","block","important");

      });

       $(".selectOptions ul").css("display","block");

  }

  contador=0;

   $(".selectOptions .selecionada").click(function(e) {

      exibeSelectUl();

      quantasLis = $(".selectOptions ul li").length;

      if(contador % 2 == 0) {                 

          $(".selectOptions .selecionada").addClass("setaCima").removeClass("setaBaixo");
          $(".selectOptions ul li").css("display","none").slideDown(400); 

          if(quantasLis > 4) {      
              $(".selectOptions ul").css('height', '175px');
              $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "scroll") ;
          } else {
              $(".selectOptions ul").css('height', 'auto');
              $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "auto") ;
          }

      } else {    

          $(".selectOptions .selecionada").addClass("setaBaixo").removeClass("setaCima");
          $(".selectOptions ul li").slideUp(400, function(){
              $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
          });
      }

      contador++;

      e.stopPropagation();

  });   


  $(document).on('click',function(e){
      if(
           $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y") == "auto" ||
           $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y") == "scroll") {
               $(".selectOptions .selecionada").trigger("click");
      }
  });

/*ai clicar na li, busca correspondência na select option e o checa (marca)*/
 //$(".selectOptions .selectOption ul li:not(:eq(0))").on( 'click',function(evt){
 $( '.selectOptions ul li' ).on( 'click', function( evt ){ 
     /*Joga a li selecionada a label*/
     $(".selectOptions .selecionada").html($(this).html());
     /*Joga a li selecionada ao topo da ul*/
     $($(this).closest('ul')).prepend($(this)); 
      // Armazena nome do maos que quer selecionar
      var li = $(this).attr("value");
      // Guarda em opcao o elemento que retornar do filtro que vai testar entre as
      // options possÃ­veis
      var opcao = $('.selectOptions select option').filter(function() {
          // testa entre as options qual delas tem o mesmo conteÃºdo que o desejado
          return $(this).attr('value') === li;
      });

      exibeSelectUl();

      // Redefine o atributo do elemento encontrado pra selecionado.
      opcao.attr('selected', true);              

 });

});
```

html

```
  <div class="selectOptions">

    <select required>
      <option value="1">Um</option>
      <option value="2">Dois</option>
      <option value="3">Três</option>
      <option value="4">Quatro</option>
      <option value="5">Cinco</option>
      <option value="6">Seis</option>
      <option value="7">Sete</option>
      <option value="8">Oito</option>
    </select>
    <label class="selecionada"></label>
    <ul></ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: Vejo que adicionou o 'important' no comando .css(..), ficou melhor assim mesmo, sem precisar criar a classe 'hidden'. Eu não sei dizer ao certo porque não estava funcionando, mas creio que era um problema com os "display" dos elementos, talvez o display do elemento <ul> estivesse sobrescrevendo o dos <li>, por isso eu adicionei o !important (que evita que outra classe sobrescreva uma propriedade daquele elemento) e acabou resolvendo.

Comment: @Renato Diniz. Mas, e aê, ficou legal? Dá idéias para melhorar esse plugin. Talvez, quem sabe, uma otimização do código.

Comment: Eu só melhoraria  a cor de fundo do elemento selecionado, porque está muito escuro em relação ao texto e dá a impressão de que a lista está desabilitada.

Comment: tem uma coisa que não está dando certo, se você for no site e abrir e a **ul**, perceberá que existe um espaço entra a **ul** aberto e a barra de rolagem que não consigo tirar. Isso acaba permitindo ver os botões no fundo. Outra dificuldade que estou tendo é como colocar a barra de rolagem para receber também o efeito de **slideDown()**  **slideUp()**